Clickable events inside a pdf canvans
I am working on a pdf annotation I'm using pdfjs and PDF-LIB,I want to add numbers in the pdf canvas and on click delete is it possible to use click events inside the pdf viewer
I have tried overlayg html elements on the pdfviewer but it doesn't work.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

hi link to my code its a legal document annotator numbers every tenth line https://codeshare.io/obqXOg
